# How to prevent an empty string or null ("") value from being appended when pushing data into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here, there is a global variable. (An array type)

```
var obj = [];
```

I will add the values input to obj to the input.

```
function firstAddData()
{
    var chozyintime = $('#ri_chozyinTime').val();

    var chozyinArray = [chozyintime];

    obj.push
    (
        {
            "ri_chozyinTime" : chozyinArray,
        }
    );
}
```

The data entered in ri_chozyinTime will be stored as an array.

```
var chozyinArray = [chozyintime];
```

Now, add the value entered in "ri_chozyinTime".

```
cur.ri_chozyinTime.push(chozyintime); // cur is obj , chozyintime is input data
```

But this is a problem.

Because it also adds an empty string.

For example, when you look at the results,

```
 ri_chozyinTime=[, , ]
```

What parts of my code should be modified to remove an empty string?

And I tried this, but it failed.

```
if(chozyintime != "" || chozyintime != null)
{
    cur.ri_chozyinTime.push(chozyintime);
}
```

How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition is incorrect. When chozyintime = `""`, `chozyintime != null` is true; when chozyintime = `null`, `chozyintime != ""` is true.
So you should use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
if(chozyintime != "" && chozyintime != null)
{
    cur.ri_chozyinTime.push(chozyintime);
}
```

Or you could just do this:

```
if(chozyintime)
{
    cur.ri_chozyinTime.push(chozyintime);
}
```

Comment: `if (chozyintime)` works due to JavaScript’s type conversion when evaluating `chozyintime` as a boolean. The condition will reject any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values for `chozyintime`, including `false`, `""`, and `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the value of `chozyintime` is `undefined`, which is neither `""` nor `null`. A better guard would be:

```
if( chozyintime && chozyintime.length > 0 ) {
    cur.ri_chozyinTime.push(chozyintime);
}
```

Comment: That can't be the problem, since they checked `chozyintime != null`, not `chozyintime !== null`. The `!=` operator treats many different types as equivalent, such as `undefined` and `null`.

Comment: It is not your answer, but it will help you solve other problems after the car! thank you so much! @DuncanThacker

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `chozyintime` is not empty, then add the values.

```js
var obj = [];
function firstAddData()
{
    var chozyintime = $('#ri_chozyinTime').val();

    if (chozyintime.trim() != "") {
      var chozyinArray = [chozyintime.trim()];

    obj.push
    (
        {
            "ri_chozyinTime" : chozyinArray,
        }
    );
    }
  
}
  
$('#test').on('click', function(){
  firstAddData();
    console.log(obj)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ri_chozyinTime">
<button id="test">push</button>
```

Comment: oh! What you suggested was included in what I thought. It seems to be a good reference. Thanks!